# Bootstrap collapse on radio button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have found this [LINK](http://codepen.io/martinkrulltott/pen/waRXgw) on Stack overflow and what i want to achieve is that when user clicks on a radio button that div stays in that state.

[image]

For example if i click on Yes the panel should be visible and if i click again on Yes it MUST not close the panel like it does now.

Anyone knows how to fix it?

here is the source code:

```
<h2>Bootstrap collapse panel with radio buttons</h2>

<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <span>Display panel: </span>

        <input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"/> Yes

        <input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" checked/> No


      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Header
                </h4>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So there is now way to do this without jQuery/javascript?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Bootstrap and css only solution: 
Remove the panel's id and add a unique class to the class instead. Change the `data-target` selector for `.collapseOne:not(.in)` on "Yes" and `.collapseOne:not.in` for "No".

```
<h2>Bootstrap collapse panel with radio buttons</h2>

<br />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <span>Display panel: </span>

        <input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseOne:not(.in)"/> Yes

        <input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".collapseOne.in" checked/> No


      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                    Header
                </h4>
          </div>
          <div class="collapseOne panel-collapse collapse">
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Content</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why class rather than ID?

Comment: In bootstrap4 use `data-target=".collapseOne:not(.show)"` and  `data-target=".collapseOne.show"` because the open class is `show`

Comment: This is brilliant, thanks! ```#target:not(.show)``` works for me.

Answer (score 10):

You can remove `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#collapseOne"`

Add values to your inputs `value="yes"` and `value="no"`

And hide/show collapse with javascript on input change event

```
$('[name="collapseGroup"]').on('change', function() {  
  if($(this).val() === "yes") {
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('show');
  } else {
    $('#collapseOne').collapse('hide');
  }
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/tmg/pen/zBYjOB?editors=1010)

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using jQuery (adding IDs to inputs):

```
var yesRadio = $('#yes'),
    noRadio = $('#no');

yesRadio.click(function () {
  if($('#collapseOne').hasClass('in')) {
    return false;
  }
});

noRadio.click(function () {
  if(!$('#collapseOne').hasClass('in')) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/QEWmeR)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by some JQuery

HTML:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- radio button with calss -->
<input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" class="yes" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne"/> Yes
<input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" class="no" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" checked/> No
<!-- content to show/hide -->
<p>
   content
 </p>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.yes').click(function(){
        $('p').slideDown(); //to show
    });
    $('.no').click(function(){
        $('p').slideUp();  //to hide
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
p{
   background: white;
   border: 1px solid #c6c6c6;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 15px;
   display: none;
 }
```

and here is the live example  https://jsfiddle.net/54jxaoas/1/

Answer (score 1):

I think better and easier solution is to use just a checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check" />

if ($('#check').is(':checked')) {
$('p').slideDown(); 
 }
else {
$('p').slideUp(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the `data-target=".collapseOne:not(.show)"` and `data-target=".collapseOne.show"` idea... if you have more than one thing (one for each radio button), and you want to have only the corresponding div showing, then you can use the [accordion mechanic](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_collapse.asp) from Bootstrap.

You need to have a `<div>` outside of both collapsed items:

```
<div id="accordion">
```

And then you just add `data-parent="#accordion"` to the buttons that trigger each collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You can change section visibility on radio button change by below code you can even gone visible two section at a time

```
<div class="form-row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label class="small mb-1" for="inputFirstName">Category Repeat</label>
    <input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" data-toggle="collapse" value="0" data-target="#accordion:not(.show),#accordiof.show"/> Yearly
    <input name="collapseGroup" type="radio" data-toggle="collapse" value="1" data-target="#accordion.show,#accordiof:not(.show)" checked/> Weekly
    <div class="panel-group panel-collapse collapse" id="accordion">
        <input type="date" name="catorder1" id="catorder1" placeholder="catorder1"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-group panel-collapse collapse" id="accordiof">
        <input type="number" name="catorder" id="catorder" placeholder="catorder"
               class="form-control"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 5 is without jQuery, you can do it like this there:

```
document.getElementById('collapseOne').addEventListener('show.bs.collapse', (e) => {
   if (/*some condition is met*/) {
      e.preventDefault();
   }
});
```